# Скрыть\показать кнопку в зависимости от выбранного селектора

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть 4 блока-кнопки на сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В зависимости от нажатия на блок: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В class="list" добавляется active
Получается Class="list active"
Вопрос: Как, при нажатии на кнопку "Оплатить" выполнялись разные функции? Нужно чтобы при выборе os_credit_card и os_yandex_qiwi выполнялась функция goToPay (), а при выборе boku и os_yandex_money выполнялась функция goToPay2.
Сейчас единственное что придумал - вставить 2 копии div блока "Оплатить", при нажатии на первый вызывать функцию goToPay, при нажатии на второй - goToPay2. Для этого хотелось бы узнать, как скрывать\показывать div блоки в зависимости от того, какой способ оплаты выбран?

Comment: javascript конкретно интересует или jquery тоже? И код бы текстом скидывать, хоть бы то, что на скрине, без вложеностей.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.QuerySelector('#click1').addEventListener ('click', ()=>{
  goToPay ()
})
document.QuerySelector('#click2').addEventListener ('click', ()=>{
  goToPay2()
})
```

Вешаешь id на те элементы при нажатии на которые должны срабатывать определенные события

Comment: Получается нужно чтобы две кнопки Оплатить были видимы одновременно?
И куда вставлять этот код?

Comment: Нет, вы вешаете id click1 на те элементы , которые при нажатии должны вызывать функцию goToPay и аналогично со второй функцией

Comment: Как это поможет мне скрыть\показать кнопку в зависимости от выбранного способа оплаты?